# How to remove all items from a kendoListBox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have two kendo list boxes they exchange items between them.  Basically an Items available and an Items selected pair.
I have Json service which controls what items are available via a Json array.
When the user selects a new filter I want both Kendo List Boxes to clear the items out before adding the new items from the server.
Currently it appends the new list from the server to the current list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filterKeyWord").click(function () {
        getResults($("#keywords"));
    });
    $("#availableReports").kendoListBox({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        connectWith: "selectedReports",
        dropSources: ["availableReports"],
        toolbar: {
            tools: ["transferTo", "transferFrom", "transferAllTo", "transferAllFrom", "remove"]
        }
    });

    $("#selectedReports").kendoListBox({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dropSources: ["selectedReports"],
        remove: function (e) {
            setSelected(e, false);
        },
        add: function (e) {
            setSelected(e, true);
        }
    });

    var mydata = { ReportName: "", UserId: "" };
    mydata.ReportName = "SomeName";
    mydata.UserId = "SomeUser";

    var crudService = "",
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: crudService + "GetReportList",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "get",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                },
                update: {
                    url: crudService + "SaveReportList2",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "post",
                },
                filter: {
                    url: crudService + "GetReportList",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "get",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                },

                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    console.log(operation);
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return JSON.stringify({ models: options.models });
                    }
                    if (operation === "read") {
                        return "request=" + JSON.stringify(mydata);
                    }
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            requestStart: function () {
                kendo.ui.progress($(".demo-section"), true);
                console.log("request start");
            },
            requestEnd: function () {
                kendo.ui.progress($(".demo-section"), false);
                console.log("request end");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("Error" + e);
            },
            change: function (e) {
                console.log("change" + this.data.length);
                setDropDownBoxes(this);
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: "number" },
                        Selected: { type: "boolean" },
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Description: { type: "string" },
                        InternalId: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    $("#saveReportList").kendoButton({
        click: function (e) {
            dataSource.sync();
        }
    });
    $("#getReportList").kendoButton({
        click: function (e) {
            mydata.ReportName = $("#keywords").val();
            dataSource.read();
        }
    });
    function setDropDownBoxes(obj) {
        var data = obj.data();
        var availableReports = $("#availableReports").data("kendoListBox");
        var selectedReports = $("#selectedReports").data("kendoListBox");
        var items = availableReports.dataItems();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].Selected) {
                    selectedReports.add(data[i]);
                }
                else {
                    availableReports.add(data[i]);
                }
            }
    }
    function setSelected(e, flag) {
        var removedItems = e.dataItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < removedItems.length; i++) {
            console.log(flag + " " + removedItems[i].ID + " " + removedItems[i].Name + " " + removedItems[i].Selected);
            var item = dataSource.get(removedItems[i].ID);
            item.Selected = flag;
            item.dirty = !item.dirty;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where in your code exactly the cleaning should be performed, but, you can use both [`remove()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox/methods/remove) and [`item()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox/methods/items) methods togheter to clear a listBox.

`remove()` method accepts a list of `li` elements, which is what `items()` returns, so it will remove the whole `li` collection from the list.

```
var listBox = $("#listBox").data("kendoListBox");
listBox.remove(listBox.items());
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/oKimACiD)